# Why does Unity 2018.3.0 gives IL2CPP error?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to create APK file of the my project. I will put it to Google Play and I need to use IL2CPP to use 64 bit. But this gives an error.

Here are my preferences:
[image]

The error codes:

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe -out="D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\tempStrip" -x="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Whitelists\Core.xml" -x "D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\..\platform_native_link.xml" -x "C:\Users\CBSLAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp675cc254.tmp" -x "C:\Users\CBSLAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1814eb62.tmp" -x "D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Assets\Mapbox\link.xml" -x "D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Assets\Mapbox\Core\Plugins\link.xml" -x "D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Assets\MapboxAR\link.xml" -d "D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --include-unity-root-assembly="D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" --include-unity-root-assembly="D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll" --dotnetruntime=il2cpp --dotnetprofile=unityaot --use-editor-options --include-directory="D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --rule-set=Conservative

stdout:
Unknown arguments : 
     --include-unity-root-assembly=D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll
     --include-unity-root-assembly=D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll
     --include-directory=D:\Unity Projects\mapImport\mapbox_try\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed
stderr:

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyLinker(IEnumerable`1, String&, String&, String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:192)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssembliesTo(String[], String[], String, String, String&, String&, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, IEnumerable`1, BuildTargetGroup, ManagedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:124)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyStripper(IEnumerable, String, String[], String[], String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, RuntimeClassRegistry, ManagedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:323)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssemblies(String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, RuntimeClassRegistry, ManagedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:216)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:203)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Also,

```
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build/UnityLinker.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyLinker (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] args, System.String& out, System.String& err, System.String linkerPath, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:192)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssembliesTo (System.String[] assemblies, System.String[] searchDirs, System.String outputFolder, System.String workingDirectory, System.String& output, System.String& error, System.String linkerPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] additionalBlacklist, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup buildTargetGroup, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:124)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (System.Collections.IEnumerable assemblies, System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, System.String[] assembliesToStrip, System.String[] searchDirs, System.String monoLinkerPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:323)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:216)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:203)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <e1c3953b4cf040ddb1400046b1c34897>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:286)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: when exactly does it happen? While building?

Comment: It happens the end of the building.